# How to Transfer data from datagridview to the active form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am working on GYM Desktop application.
Here with Product Entry form I insert the data in database table. And when I click the 'get data' button all the records appear in different form (Product_List) in datagridview.
Now on double clicking on any particular row(in Product_List form) I want to get the data of that particular row in my currently active Product_Entry Form, so i can update or delete the data.
so how can i get the data of that row on currently active Product Entry form ?

here is the code on mouse double_click on row in datagridview:

```
  private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs 
 e)
    {

        Product_Entry pe = new Product_Entry();
        pe.textBox1.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        pe.textBox2.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        pe.comboBox1.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        pe.comboBox2.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        pe.textBox3.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        pe.textBox4.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        pe.textBox5.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        pe.textBox6.Text = 
 dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        pe.ShowDialog();

    }
```

[image: Product_Entry Form]

[image: Product List Form]

Answer (score 0):

Use of global variable may solve this. declare a global variable like
`public static string ProductId= "";` in your `datagridview` form. Then on `dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick`  event set your `productId` like

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ProductId = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(); //your second form
        frm2.Show(); 
    }
```

Then in second form (where you want to show the value) receive the `ProductId` in `Form2_Load` event like

```
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Form1.ProductId; //label is your control to show data
    }
```

Like this you can receive all data in second form or you can write a `database query` with `productid` to fetch data from `database`. For more [see this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/)

Comment: you are doing the same thing...creating the new object of form2.